# Heat capacity from phonon dispersion curves

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, crystals

I have phonon dispersion curves for a crystal with two atoms per unit cell.
The following figure is phonon dispersion curves for the same crystal as above. $q_{BZ}$ denotes the wavevector at the BZ boundary. The direction of $q$ is antisymmetric, so the LA, LO branches are doubly degenerate. LA/TA, LO/TO denote longitudinal or transverse and acoustic and optical branches.

How would the temperature dependence of the lattice contribution to the heat capacity of this crystal be, in the low temperature limit and high temperature limit? The final page of [this document](http://physics.usask.ca/%7Ealex/phys470/week4.pdf) shows the longitudinal and tranverse, acoustic and optical branches.

If we know that $$C_v = 3\frac{V}{(2\pi)^3} k_B 4\pi \int_{0}^{k_D} \frac{(\hbar \omega (k)/k_B T)^2e^{\hbar\omega (k)/k_B T}}{(e^{\hbar \omega (k)/k_B T}-1)^2}$$

What is the simplification for $\omega(k)$ that I use to solve for $C_v$?

[image]

Comment: You know that phonons obey Bose-statisttics and from the plots you can find the energy of phonon, $\omega=\omega(q)$. Then, from thermodynamics, you also know that $C\sim \partial^2U/\partial T^2$, where $U$ is the total internal energy. To calculate $U$, you should perform integration of $\omega(q)$ over $q$ with Bose-statistics. High-T and low-T limits can be found as the corresponding expansions of the integrand

Comment: @ArtemAlexandrov, thanks for your reply. How do I find $\omega (q)$?

Comment: On your plot I can see these curves, $\omega=\omega(q)$

Comment: But I don't have any quantitative information to do anything mathematical with it, right?

Comment: At first glance, you can perform fitting of curves and then numerical differentiation (if the curves were obtained numerically/experimentally). From the other hand, it seems that the problem of 1D crystall with two different atoms per cell can be solved analytically

Comment: @ArtemAlexandrov, no, the curves were not obtained numerically. How would you solve the problem of two atoms in a crystal, and find its heat capacity?

Comment: @ArtemAlexandrov, I have added some additional information in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, as I understand the question is: how can one calculate the dispersion relation for diatomic 1D chain and then derive the heat capacity?

The quite detailed derivation of the dispersion relation can be find [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/chemistry/5-62-physical-chemistry-ii-spring-2008/lecture-notes/23_562ln08.pdf) (p. 8-9).

Having obtained the analytical expressions for the dispersion relation, we can compute the internal energy of our crystal,

$$U\propto\int\frac{d\omega\,\omega}{e^{\beta\omega}-1},$$
where, for simplicity, we can consider the limit of small momenta and expand $\omega(q)$ in terms of $q$. Then, perform change of variables, it seems possible to evaluate appearing integral. Finally, we use
$$C\propto\frac{\partial^2U}{\partial T^2}$$
to obtain the desired answer.

Comment: I'm still confused. what is $\omega$ here? Do we consider both the acoustic and optical modes?

Comment: @megamence acoustic mode is the mode that goes to zero at $q=0$, optical mode goes to non-zero at $q=0$.

Comment: yes. So do I write two separate integrals with those modes and sum them up? I appreciate all your advice!

Comment: @megamence in my opinion yes

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approximations might be all that is required:

- the Einstein model for the optical branches
- the Debye model for the acoustical branches

So estimate $\omega_E$ and $\omega_D$ from the dispersion curves and add their contributions to $c_v$.

Comment: How do you estimate $\omega _E$ and $\omega _D$ from these curves?

Comment: @megamence The Debye frequency is the cutoff of the acoustical branch at the Brillouin zone boundary. The Einstein frequency an average over the optical branches. If this is homework, you really need to study more in your book.